# Python code saying: "min() arg is an empty sequence"

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function in python to generate and find tweets. But when i call this defined function I get a strange error saying min() arg is an empty sequence. I have attached the definition and the calling functions below.

```
import re
import json
import xml
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
!pip install TwitterAPI
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

import requests

# disabling urllib3 warnings
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

keywords =  ["donkey", "condition", "motion"] # INSERT YOUR CODE 
print(keywords)  

ONSUMER_KEY = "xL6gbYUG6uNteXxtaVzSopZOe"
CONSUMER_SECRET =  
"tvH5dzMtDeZ5u8Tvw2fxq8sCnWU07KenVXcNAEplKBD4uu6AlG"
OAUTH_TOKEN =  "1260044898767495170-i60LmXDg7XtEGaiBiTtBXNhSTtRHVk"
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET =  "L7yCVjWRB9MJhJL0kmnc5DWHlgYfaslrPWLybcXZyswkv"

# Authenticating with your application credentials
api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, 
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, api_version='2')

print(api)

PLACE_LAT = 32.7767 # INSERT YOUR CODE
PLACE_LON = -96.797 # INSERT YOUR CODE
DELTA_LAT = 1.0
DELTA_LON = 1.0

def retrieve_tweets(api, keyword, batch_count, total_count, latitude, 
longitude, delta_lat, delta_lon):
   
    """
    collects tweets using the Twitter search API
    
    api:         Twitter API instance
    keyword:     search keyword
    batch_count: maximum number of tweets to collect per each request
    total_count: maximum number of tweets in total
    latitude:    latitude of the location centre from where tweets 
    are retrieved
    longitude:   longitude of the location centre from where tweets 
    are retrieved
    delta_lat:   latitude delta (from the location centre) in degrees
    delta_lon:   longitude delta (from the location centre) in 
    degrees
    """

    
    # the collection of tweets to be returned
    tweets_unfiltered = []
    tweets = []
    
    # the number of tweets within a single query
    batch_count = str(batch_count)
    
    '''
    You are required to insert your own code where instructed to 
    perform the first query to Twitter API.
    Hint: revise the practical session on Twitter API on how to 
    perform query to Twitter API.
    '''    
    resp = api.request('tweets/search/recent', {'query':  keyword, # 
    INSERT YOUR CODE 
                                     'max_results': total_count, # 
    INSERT YOUR CODE
                                     'tweet.fields': {'lang':'en'},      
                                     'place.fields':{
                                     'geo': {
                                     "type": "Feature",
                                     "bbox": [
                                     longitude - delta_lon,
                                     latitude - delta_lat,
                                     longitude + delta_lon,
                                     latitude + delta_lat
                                      ],
                                      "properties": {}
                                      }}})
    

    # check first if there was an error
    if ('errors' in resp.json()):
        errors = resp.json()['title']
        if (errors == 'Invalid Request'):
            print('Too many attempts to load tweets or too many 
            tweets to load.')
            print('You need to wait for a few minutes before 
            accessing Twitter API again or reduce max_results.')
    

    
    if ('statuses' in resp.json()):
        tweets_unfiltered += resp.json()['statuses']
        tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if 
        ((tweet['retweeted'] != True) and ('RT @' not in 
        tweet['text']))]
    
        # find the max_id_str for the next batch
        ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
        max_id_str = str(min(ids))

        # loop until as many tweets as total_count is collected
        number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
        while number_of_tweets < total_count:

            resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': keyword,
                                             'count': total_count,
                                             'lang':'en',
                                             'result_type': 'recent', 
                                             'max_id': max_id_str,
                                             'geocode':'{},{}, 
                                            {}mi'.format(latitude, 
                 longitude, delta_lat, delta_lon)}) #INSERT YOUR CODE
                          

            if ('statuses' in resp.json()):
                tweets_unfiltered += resp.json()['statuses']
                tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if 
                ((tweet['retweeted'] != True) and ('RT @' not in 
                 tweet['text']))]
 
                ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
                max_id_str = str(min(ids))
            
                number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
        
            print("{} tweets are collected for keyword {}. Last tweet 
            created at {}".format(number_of_tweets, 
                                                                                    
            keyword, 
                                                                                    
            tweets[number_of_tweets-1]['created_at']))

    
    ids = [int(tweet['id']) for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
    max_id_str = str(min(ids))
    
    tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if (('RT @' not in 
    tweet['text']) & (tweet['lang'] == 'en'))]
    
    
    # loop until as many tweets as total_count is collected
    number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
    
    while number_of_tweets < total_count:

    
        resp = api.request('tweets/search/recent', {'query': keyword, 
        # INSERT YOUR CODE
                                         'max_results':total_count,                                     
                                         'until_id': max_id_str,
                                         'tweet.fields': 
                                         {'lang':'en'},      
                                         'place.fields':{
                                         'geo': {
                                         "type": "Feature",
                                         "bbox": [
                                         longitude - delta_lon,
                                         latitude - delta_lat,
                                         longitude + delta_lon,
                                         latitude + delta_lat
                                         ],
                                         "properties": {}
                                         }}})

            
        tweets_unfiltered += resp
        tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if (('RT @' 
        not in tweet['text']) & (tweet['lang'] == 'en'))]
 
        ids = [int(tweet['id']) for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
        max_id_str = str(min(ids))
            
        number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
        
        print("{} tweets are collected for keyword {}. 
        ".format(number_of_tweets, keyword))
   
    return tweets

k1_tweets = retrieve_tweets(api,'donkey',50,200,PLACE_LAT,PLACE_LON, 
DELTA_LAT, DELTA_LON )
k2_tweets = 
retrieve_tweets(api,'condition',50,200,PLACE_LAT,PLACE_LON, 
DELTA_LAT, DELTA_LON)
k3_tweets = retrieve_tweets(api,'motion',50,200,PLACE_LAT,PLACE_LON, 
DELTA_LAT, DELTA_LON)
```

I have edited the code to add the rest of it.

If someone knows what is causing tje error it would be great.

Comment: Culd you paste the entire stack trace? Makes it easyer to see where the error originates

Comment: You need to handle cases if the id lists are empty.

Comment: the error is not strange, it is telling you exactly what the problem is: when you call `str(min(ids))` the `ids` is empty, which in turn means `tweets_unfiltered` was empty

Comment: There are multiples `min()` function, it's difficult for us to understand which one don't work, did you tried to `print` the list in which you apply the `min()` function ?

Comment: Its saying the one in line 93 which is above tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if (('RT @' not in tweet['text']) & (tweet['lang'] == 'en'))]